# How does iPhone with 1GB RAM have similar performance to Android phones with 2GB RAM

Tags: android, ios, iphone, performance, multiprocessing

With the release of the latest iPhone 6/6+, I have been wondering how the iPhones compete against the competition even with lower RAM. What is the fundamental difference in the OS that lets iOS run on less beefy hardware, especially the RAM?

Comment: It is a technical question.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference is the number of layers between your application and the hardware.

This is pure subtraction, in Android your application is running inside a virtual machine and this kind of abstraction has a lot of downsides, including lower performance, they promise that the ART runtime will improve a lot this situation (http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#ART).

In iOS, there's no such thing, your application is running directly in the operational system, there's a huge difference also because Apple every year tries to improve low level APIs, a sample I can use is Metal API (https://developer.apple.com/metal/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok iPhone has more Performance then any Android Device because Apple complie the Program Code to machine Code. Androide use java, java will only compile to Bytecode. 
In ordenarie Performance test you have factor 20-50 between them. And Java need a JVM with a memory footprint of 70-100 MB.
Next Apple has better optimization on the OS.